# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, arrays

I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:49)
/home/panda/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

for the following program. here Names is a string array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
    {
        if(names[i].charAt(1) == names[j].charAt(1))
        {
            if ((names[i].substring(2)).compareTo((names[j].substring(2)))>0)
                {
                    temp = names[i];
                    names[i] = names[j];
                    names[j] = temp;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no error in your question, just code.

Comment: charAt. Case matters. :)

Comment: Thanks @Dewick47 ! Damn I'm such a noobie

Comment: @VarunIyer It happens to all of us at some point or another!

Comment: @VarunIyer you have a very clear error message. Your code is trying to reach a string array with an index that exceeds the length of it. I would set a breakpoint to see when it occurs. It might be that you try charAt(1) for shorter string value.

Comment: code not complete, some variables NOT DEFINED (names ,temp, n) ?!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error message:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

For starter, A String is an array of char. Like any other array if you try to access a negative index or an index greater than the size of the actual array you will get an "OutOfBound" Exception. Also please take note that Array are 0-base index.

For your particular problem, As stated in the comment by @Kirill Ch I would set a break point and find where you try to access the index that is out of bound. It depend of the data in the names[] array

Hope it helped